# charging a 12V calcium battery

Tags: batteries, 12v, charging

I have recently purchased a Halfords 12V calcium battery second hand off facebook. I was told it was about 6 month old ( it does look new ).

The problem is it will not charge using my trickle charger' that works fine for all my other batteries.

Do these new calcium type need some special charger?

Comment: How about you locating a data sheet for it to see what charge levels it needs?

Comment: How much voltage can you measure across it? If you have a "too" smart charger, there are many ways to cheat to get it going and potentially save your battery. It might be dead though.

Comment: Calcium batteries require a slightly higher voltage charger, I believe it's more like 15V.

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is it will not charge using my trickle charger

The [typical](http://www.powerstream.com/SLA.htm) lead acid charging voltage is between 2.15 volts per cell (12.9 volts for a 6 cell battery) and 2.35 volts per cell (14.1 volts for a 6 cell battery).

The [ideal](http://www.powerstream.com/SLA.htm) charging voltage for a calcium battery is 14.8V for the recombination process to properly occur.

The above indicates that your trickle charge will not deliver enough charge to completely recharge you battery.

If it does charge, it might be worth considering whether your alternator is suitable for a calcium batttery, (I think most bring the voltage to around 13.6V).

Be very careful around the battery, the voltage is small but the current can be massive, you do not want a silver necklace to fall between the terminals!!

Comment: @Johnboy you're welcome.  However, I'd advise extreme caution when working around car batteries, (especially as I don't know your level of electrical knowledge).  Check out this : http://thegreynomads.activeboard.com/t55542005/calcium-battery-exploded-like-shotgun-blast/

Comment: Hi Sean thanks for the advice, my first year into my apprenticeship as a mechanic back in the 70's taught me to respect the 12v battery when I almost melted a 13mm spanner removing a starter motor ( battery still connected ) ... :)

Answer (score 2):

The battery is most likely scrap.
Calcium batteries are lead batteries that tiny amounts of calcium added to the plate to improve performance -- the problem is they can be very very difficult sometimes impossible to recharge if battery has become deeply discharge even with a special charger. Most smart chargers simply will refuse start the charging process  . There are special smart chargers that *sometimes* work if left on for weeks or sometimes an ordinary high output old style charger if left on a high setting will eventually start the charging process but this way  needs care.

Answer (score 2):

The calcium is used as a hardener like antimony was used, a benefit of calcium over antimony is it creates less gassing and that's why batteries can be truly be sealed and maintenance free. The calcium does create higher internal resistance which has to be overcome with higher amperage. The voltage must remain consistently at 12.66 volts to protect vital electronic components. The charging process creates heat that lowers the internal resistance then the battery begins to convert the chemical process.

Answer (score 0):

JUMP STARTING A DISCHARGED BATTERY.

If you connect your flat battery to a good battery (with jumper leads) then connect smart charger to the discharged battery it will start the charging process. Leave batteries connected for about 10-15 minutes then disconnect charged battery & the charger should continue to charge the discharge battery.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Did you notice that the question is about a calcium battery? Your answer might be relevant to a question on standard lead-acid batteries but are you sure it is correct in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Car batteries are starting batteries - their internal resistance is low since approx., 450 amps (for petrol engines) and 800 amps (diesel) and even more need to flow to start the engine. Internal resistance goes up (high) with age and use - eventually even if the battery goes up to a decent 12.5 volts, it may still not charge enough due to high resistance and would not start an engine since not enough amps (current) can flow through it due to its high resistance too. Power is Volts x amps. If you reduce the amps, power goes down and the potential in volts goes down drastically with it. 
So if a battery cannot charge, it is either that its internal resistance has gone up permanently - or the charger does not have the potential to push enough current through it high internal resistance. The best way is to take it to a battery shop since they can easily check this and most do it for free. This would save you buying a better charger since of if its bad, no charger would be able to bring it back to decent.

I HAVE TO WARN YOU THOUGH - ABOUT A PRACTICE I READ HERE - WHICH IS CONNECTING A GOOD BATTERY TO IT FOR ABOUT 10 TO 15 MINUTES - which is why I decided to write.
If you connect a relative new discharged battery to a relatively new charged battery (both good and hence with low internal resistance) the charged batteries will attempt to charge the discharged battery. With no resistance to slow this charging process and the amount of current that can flow due to low resistance, the charged unit can easily - really easily overheat in FAR LESS THAN 10 MINUTES as they rapidly drain and the discharged battery can overheat as it attempts to charge at well above its design capabilities. What happens is that the discharged battery is at a disadvantage and will not be in a position to charge above a certain point, but the fully charged battery will try anyway and overheat itself for sure. Anyway, you could ruin both - you would damage the new battery for sure since the cells are connected internally and overheating these causes permanent damage including melting the battery body and less current will be able to flow through in future - you are dealing with exceptionally high amps that can weld metal and cause fires. It is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late but I just saw this thread. Calcium batteries are lead acid  batteries, however their chemical composition is slightly different to provide lower internal resistance and therefore greater cranking Amp supply when compared with a same size AGM, wet cell or Gel type.

They do require a slightly higher voltage when charging (14.8v) for a 12v battery, failure to maintain a good charge or if stored for a long time in a partial state of charge will cause loss of capacity.

Comment: Okay Thank you very much for your comments 